# jsonpath query in a simple html page

Tags: javascript, jsonpath

I'm developing a simple basic html page that inculde javascript code.
I would like to process a json string doing querys that use jsonpath expression.

I'm looking for the simplest, most recent and most robust way to use jsonpath querys inside a simple html page.
This means that I can not use any node.js, npm, builder, pre-builder or other things like that.
I would just like to include a js library in the html page and call its functions.

Something like this would be great
https://github.com/dchester/jsonpath#readme
but it does'nt seem to be any simple way to make it work without node.

Thanks

Comment: _I would just like to include a js library in the html page and call its functions_. That is exactly what jsonpath is and do. Could you clearify why you dont want to use it?

Comment: Hi @wayneOS, maybe you're talking about [this](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/):
If so, I felt a little bit confused when I saw [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jsonpath/downloads) that the major version is zero and that its last update has been done in 2007.

Comment: I was talking about the link in your question. You don't need to be worry about last updates made in 2007. JSON-standard hasn't changed in quite a while so there is no need to update jsonpath.